# How to restrict the jenkins pipeline docker agent in specific slave?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have several jenkins slaves configured and only label with `dockerserver` has docker env, then how can I restrict the jenkins pipeline docker agent in this slave?

Below `Jenkinsfile` doesn't work, the `agent` inside `stage` will overwrite the defined slave `dockerserver`

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'dockerserver' }
    stages {
        stage('Back-end') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'maven:3-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
        stage('Front-end') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It may pick other slave which doesn't have docker supported

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After read the guideline more, noticed it was stated https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label.

[image]

It shall be configured in the jenkins global(system) configuration

Answer (score 18):

Just had the same problem, seems to work for me like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'dockerserver' } // if you don't have other steps, 'any' agent works
    stages {
        stage('Back-end') {
            agent {
                docker {
                  label 'dockerserver'  // both label and image
                  image 'maven:3-alpine'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
        stage('Front-end') {
            agent {
              docker {
                label 'dockerserver'  // both label and image
                image 'node:7-alpine' 
              }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution won't work if you want to specify `dockerfile true` as `dockerfile` is not valid within the `docker` closure.  If you are using a dockerfile @Larry Cai's solution worked for me