# Docker command not found in local Jenkins multi branch pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have **BookStore** Spring Boot project that needs to be deployed through Jenkins. Docker installed in my local machine (macOS) and Jenkinsfile created as follows

```
pipeline 
{
     agent 
     {
         docker
          {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            //This exposes application through port 8081 to outside world
            args '-u root -p 8081:8081 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  '
         }
    } 
    stages 
     {
        stage('Build') 
         {
              steps 
              {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
              }
          }

        stage('Test') 
        {
            steps {
                //sh 'mvn test'
                sh 'echo "test"'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    //junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                    sh 'echo "test"'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deliver for development')
        {
                    when {
                        branch 'development'
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver-for-development.sh'
                        input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                    }
        }

        stage('Deploy for production')
        {
            when {
                branch 'production'
            }
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deploy-for-production.sh'
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
            }
        }

        stage('Deliver') {
        when {
              branch 'production'
           }
            steps {
                sh 'bash ./jenkins/deliver.sh'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I created multi-branch pipeline in Jenkins and when I try to run it, I got following error

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/BookStore_master-VPWQ32ZZPV7CVOXNI4XOB3VSGH56MTF3W34KXKZFJKOBMSGLRZQQ@tmp/durable-70dd5a81/script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found

script returned exit code 127
```

This looks strange to me as docker available in local machine, and also configured **Global Tool Configuration** section with appropriate details as shown below. I looked into several posts and none of the solutions worked so far.

[image: Global Tool Configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by retrieving Docker and Maven values from **Global Tool Configuration** section and adding them to environment PATH as shown below

Updated **Jenkinsfile**:

```
node {

    stage('Initialize')
    {
        def dockerHome = tool 'MyDocker'
        def mavenHome  = tool 'MyMaven'
        env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${mavenHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    }

    stage('Checkout') 
    {
        checkout scm
    }

      stage('Build') 
           {
            sh 'uname -a'
            sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'  
          }

        stage('Test') 
        {
            //sh 'mvn test'
            sh 'ifconfig' 
        }

        stage('Deliver') 
          {
                sh 'bash ./jenkins/deliver.sh'
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution that does not rely on switching from declarative `pipeline` syntax to scripted `node` syntax?

Comment: You can NickofThyme answer.

Comment: Confirming that it still works as a charm. Thank you @Jadda

Comment: Glad it helped you @ArtemSolovev

Comment: not working, change the jenkins file with your first option

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue on the Mac and the following answer helped me.

[docker: command not found ( mac mini ) only happens in jenkins shell step but work from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043004/docker-command-not-found-mac-mini-only-happens-in-jenkins-shell-step-but-wo/58688536#58688536).

The solution is to add the following line into the /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.176.3/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist file so that Jenkins able to find the docker command from the host machine.

```html
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/:/Users/Kh0a/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did not have the last element of your <string> on my Mac (/Users/<usr>/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin), but I just specified the rest of the elements, restarted Jenkins, and docker started working from Jenkins.

Comment: This solution works but is not persistent. You can add Env variable into the jenkins interface.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it thanks to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/50029962/6943587.

You need to specify the docker label, aka which agent(s) have docker. There are two ways to do this, that I know of.

### (Option 1 - preferred) Set docker label in Jenkinsfile

Set the agent as docker image with docker agent label.

```java
// Jenkinsfile

pipeline {
  // Assign to docker agent(s) label, could also be 'any'
  agent {
    label 'docker' 
  }

  stages {
    stage('Docker node test') {
      agent {
        docker {
          // Set both label and image
          label 'docker'
          image 'node:7-alpine'
          args '--name docker-node' // list any args
        }
      }
      steps {
        // Steps run in node:7-alpine docker container on docker agent
        sh 'node --version'
      }
    }

    stage('Docker maven test') {
      agent {
        docker {
          // Set both label and image
          label 'docker'
          image 'maven:3-alpine'
        }
      }
      steps {
        // Steps run in maven:3-alpine docker container on docker agent
        sh 'mvn --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### (Option 2) Set docker label in configuration

Set the "docker label" in the Jenkins configuration under "Pipeline Model Definition", per the Jenkins docs [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label). This will only run the pipeline builds on agents with this label. Then you can create your pipeline like so...

```java
// Jenkinsfile

pipeline {
  // "Top-level" agent is assigned to docker agents via Jenkins pipeline configuration
  agent none

  stages {
    stage('Docker node test') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'node:7-alpine'
          args '--name docker-node' // list any args
        }
      }
      steps {
        // Steps run in node:7-alpine docker container on docker agent
        sh 'node --version'
      }
    }
    
    stage('Docker maven test') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'maven:3-alpine'
        }
      }
      steps {
        // Steps run in maven:3-alpine docker container on docker agent
        sh 'mvn --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

> Option 1 is preferred over option 2 because the Jenkinsfile configures
> what machine(s) to run the docker agents on without relying on the
> Jenkins pipeline configuration which could be deleted or edited in the
> future.

Comment: I have not tested this. Looks like a winner

Comment: If you go with the option 1 without adding label 'docker' to Jenkins configuration you'll get ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘docker’. EDIT: nope, I get this message event after adding it there. The first option doesn't work for me.

Comment: @terreb if you are getting that error it sounds like the label is working but that your Jenkins instance does NOT have any nodes (aka machines) that have the docker label. You must add the `docker` label to the machines that you have installed docker so Jenkins knows where to run the job.

Comment: @Nickofthyme, you're right. Someone else deployed Jenkins and I figured out it's running inside Docker container, but docker host is not exposed inside the container.

Comment: both above options are not working for me

Comment: Do you have Jenkins agents with docker installed and labeled as `docker`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have chosen *install automatically* option in Global Tool Configuration section, Jenkins will not look for the docker in your system.

You can resolve this issue by unchecking the *install automatically* option for docker in Global Tool Configuration section

- download docker installer,
- install it and
- give the path of installer to Jenkins.

Example screenshot is below.

[Setup docker installer path in jenkins under Global Tool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ6H5.png)

Comment: I have done this and I still get `docker: command not found`.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with automated docker installer. I encountered the same issue on docker on centos 7.

I downloaded the docker cli executables from https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/ and extracted them into jenkins docker volume on host (/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/docker). Then copied from /var/jenkins_home/docker to /usr/bin using shell on docker container.

After coping the executables, the build worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had docker command issues because I was using jenkins-lts which is also a docker. After trying to debug for quite a while, I realized referencing docker command with in a docker might be an issue. I stopped the jenkins-lts service, downloaded jenkins.war file and ran the same pipeline script with docker command. It started working. My pipeline script has agent any, it still works in jenkins.war version of jenkins

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows
Follow from here:-
https://www.katacoda.com/courses/jenkins/build-docker-images

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the line separator Unix and Mac Os : "\n" in your ".sh" files with your code editor. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac user, adding path to Docker in tools should do the trick. please check the screenshots.

[image: Adding path to Docker in tools should do the trick.]

Also update Jenkinsfile

[image]

Answer (score -1):

add `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` while running container