# "Docker: command not found" from Jenkins on MacOS

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When running jobs from Jenkinsfile with Pipeline syntax and a Docker agent, the pipeline fails with "Docker: command not found." I understand this to mean that either (1) Docker is not installed; or (2) Jenkins is not pointing to the correct Docker installation path. My situation is very similar to this issue: [Docker command not found in local Jenkins multi branch pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916740/docker-command-not-found-in-local-jenkins-multi-branch-pipeline) . Jenkins is installed on MacOS and running off of `localhost:8080`. Docker is also installed (v18.06.0-ce-mac70)./

That user's solution included a switch from `pipeline` declarative syntax to `node` scripted syntax. However I want to resolve the issue while retaining the declarative syntax.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:7-alpine'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Unit') {
      steps {
        sh 'node -v'
        sh 'npm -v'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Error message**

```
docker inspect -f . node:7-alpine
docker: command not found

docker pull node:7-alpine
docker: command not found
```

In Jenkins Global Tool Configuration, for Docker installations I tried both (1) install automatically (from docker.com); and (2) local installation with installation root `/usr/local/`.

All of the relevant plugins appears to be installed as well.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58688536/8160903

(Add Docker's path to Homebrew Jenkins plist ***/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.176.3/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist***)

Comment: You save my day

Comment: the new directory should be `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins-lts/`

Answer (score 0):

I would check the user who is running the jenkins process and make sure they are part of the docker group.

Comment: this would AFAIK only help with access to the docker socket, not to the executable.

Comment: Unfortunately the Docker documentation on setting up groups for MacOS links to the general Getting Started docs, which itself links to the the Linux documentation, which does not in fact work for MacOS >_< https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#test-docker-version

Comment: there is no docker group anymore. See: https://forums.docker.com/t/no-more-docker-group/9123. Also: the staff group does not work either. sudo is required

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the full path of `docker` executable on your machine to Jenkins at `Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration`.

I've seen it happen sometimes that the user which has started Jenkins doesn't have the executable's location on `$PATH`.