# Does't work build image in kubernetes pod using jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, docker-build

I'm trying to build an image using the kubernetes pod in jenkins. The image that I'm using for pod is docker:latest and on it I'm trying to build and push in to my docker-repo. Docker-pipeline installed. When I try to do this, it gives me an error.

```
Commit message: "Update jenkinsPipeline"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Building image)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t testnginx/test1mynginx:latest .
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-pipelines4@tmp/durable-6e84af99/script.sh: 1. 
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-pipelines4@tmp/durable-6e84af99/script.sh: docker: not 
found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Push image to registry)
Stage "Push image to registry" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is how my kubernetes cloud settings look like in Jenkins.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vqca.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd2Mh.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQ4L.png)

The pipeline I'm using.

```
pipeline {

    environment {
        registry = "testnginx/test1mynginx"
        registryCredential = 'dockerhub-creds'
        dockerImage = ''
        }
    agent { label 'jenkins-slave' }
    stages {
      stage('Building image') {
          steps{
              script {
                  dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":latest"
                }
              }
            }
      stage('Push image to registry') {
           steps{
              script {
                 docker.withRegistry( '', registryCredential ) {
                 dockerImage.push()
               }
             }
           }
         }
      }
    }
```

If I try to go to the docker image and write dockev -v there, then there will already be a docker in it Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe. I think I’m missing something. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you checked if you have `docker` in your `PATH`?

Comment: @DawidKruk Where should it be? All pod settings in the screenshots. Thank

Comment: It looks like you have a similar issue to the one describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916740/docker-command-not-found-in-local-jenkins-multi-branch-pipeline . Please take a look and let know if it helped.