# How can I run something during agent setup in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

Our current Jenkins pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {

  agent {
    docker {
      label 'linux'
      image 'java:8'
      args '-v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle'
    }
  }

  environment {
    GRADLE_USER_HOME = '/.gradle'
    GRADLE_PROPERTIES = credentials('gradle.properties')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'cp ${GRADLE_PROPERTIES} ${GRADLE_USER_HOME}/'
        sh './gradlew clean check'
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    always {
      junit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
    }
  }

}
```

We mount `/.gradle` because we want to reuse cached data between builds. The problem is, if the machine is a brand new build machine, the directory on the host does not yet exist.

Where do I put setup logic which runs *before*, so that I can ensure this directory exists before the docker image is run?

Answer (score 2):

You can run a prepare stage before all the stages and change agent after that

```
pipeline {

  agent { label 'linux' } // slave where docker agent needs to run

  environment {
    GRADLE_USER_HOME = '/.gradle'
    GRADLE_PROPERTIES = credentials('gradle.properties')
  }

  stages {

    stage('Prepare') {
      // prepare host
    }

    stage('Build') {

      agent {
        docker {
          label 'linux' // should be same as slave label
          image 'java:8'
          args '-v /home/tester/.gradle:/.gradle'
        }
      }

      steps {
        sh 'cp ${GRADLE_PROPERTIES} ${GRADLE_USER_HOME}/'
        sh './gradlew clean check'
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    always {
      junit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
    }
  }

}
```

[Specifying a Docker Label](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label)

> Pipeline provides a global option in the Manage Jenkins page, and on the Folder level, for specifying which agents (by Label) to use for running Docker-based Pipelines.

[How to restrict the jenkins pipeline docker agent in specific slave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981735/how-to-restrict-the-jenkins-pipeline-docker-agent-in-specific-slave)

Comment: How can I be sure that the `agent{docker{label 'linux'}}` will get the same agent that the prepare stage got?

Comment: updated for restricting docker agent on certain host

Comment: So is there a hidden detail here? Both times it only specifies a label, but is there a guarantee that you'll get the same host even if there are 18 hosts with the same label?

Comment: You can't have duplicate node names (Jenkins Slaves) which is used as hosts for docker

Comment: We don't actually have duplicate node names. 'linux' is a label we apply to 18 hosts which all run various distros of Linux. We certainly can't reduce ourselves to running on a single host anyway, we barely have enough processing power to build everything as it is. :(